# Why Firebase's getAuth() returns an object with past expiry

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

Is that possible that [`getAuth()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/getAuth.html) will return an object with `expires` in the past?

I was under impression that if `expires` is in the past, `getAuth()` will return `null`. But, it looks like I'm wrong.

Here is how I proved I'm wrong:

```
var resolve = {
  auth: function($q) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var authData = rootRef.getAuth();

    if (authData === null) {
      ...
    } else {
      var now = new Date() / 1000;
      console.log('Authenticated!');
      console.log('          Auth expiry: ' + authData.expires);
      console.log('                  Now: ' + now);
      console.log('Is expiry in the past? ' + (authData.expires < now ? 'YES' : 'NO'));
      defer.resolve();
    }

    return defer.promise;
  }
};
```

and here is the output:

```
Authenticated!
          Auth expiry: 1415276774
                  Now: 1415276804.45
Is expiry in the past? YES
```

If I refresh the page after getting the above output, `getAuth()` returns `null` as expected.

To reproduce the issue I do:

1. Login using email and password
2. Close the app (browser's tab) **before** the login session expires (I experimented with 1 minute sessions, but same happens with other lengths sessions)
3. Wait until the login session expires
4. Open the app (at this point the code above runs and produces the output above)

Any ideas?

Comment: It's possible your client clock is out of sync with the Firebase server. If you loop the getAuth() method or have an onAuth() callback, do you eventually see a log out event? Are you changing the Session Length setting on the Login & Auth screen in your dashboard while performing these tests? - I believe the client might cache the expected expiry time each time it authenticates

Comment: @Chris: Session length stays the same, I don't change it when reproducing the issue. I added `onAuth()` callback, and I can see first the **log in** event (with the expiry in the past) and then the **log out** event. I believe that the **log in** event shouldn't happen when the expiry is in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chris mentioned in his comment, this appears to be due to differences between client and server times. The `expires` time specified in the authentication payload is generated by the server using the server's time, but this is likely to be at least slightly different than the one of your client. The important thing to remember is that the client is indeed expired using the TTL you specified, enforced by the server.

I created a simple example to invoke `getAuth()` every second, and log the difference between the expiration time and current local time upon each request. When tested across multiple iterations, each one looked as follows:

```
...
session time remaining:  2.23s
session time remaining:  1.23s
session time remaining:  0.23s
session time remaining: -0.76s
session time remaining: -1.77s
session expired
session expired
session expired
...
```

In short, the client is immediately notified by the server once the session has expired, but the client's timestamp is a few seconds different, which is why the expiration returned from `getAuth()` may appear to be in the past.

Comment: Why `getAuth()` is dependent on client's time rather than server's time? Is that because it's synchronous?

Comment: I tried to check the log in status using the asynchronous method (`onAuth()`) and the issue about doesn't happen. Why is happening only with the synchronous method?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko The `getAuth()` method is in no way dependent upon the client's time. The expiration occurs when the server *tells* the client that the authentication is expired. The client never compares the expiration time timestamp against the local time, because that would leave security holes. Note that these should never be out of sync for more than a few seconds (unless your client's time is drastically off). It is just as likely to occur with the async method, but you might have more trouble timing it exactly.

Comment: I'm still confused. Let's assume that the client and the server time are in sync (say no more than few seconds difference). My point is that after the session expires (say few hours later), `getAuth()` should always be `null`. Is that the expected behaviour? If yes, then the example outlined above is a counterexample.

Comment: Every time the app starts or the page refreshes, the client must connect to the server, attempt to resume the session with the persisted credential, and the server will respond with the validity of the session. If the credential is expired, it will be blown away and the client is never authenticated. If the session is valid, the client will authenticate until the server tells it that it is invalid. If the client is offline when the application starts, or goes offline before the session expires, then the client will not be notified of expiration until it is able to reconnect to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! However, it doesn't explain why the server responds with a valid session after it's been expired. In my case, the client is always online, so when the app starts (step 4 above) and executes `getAuth()`, I expect the server to return `null` because the session has expired! Instead, the server returns a valid session. Why is that?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko *When* does it return online, and for how long? Once, upon immediate app refresh? After hours of being online and expired? If you get it once upon page refresh, that is expected - every page in Firebase starts in an "offline" state before it has connected to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your patience :) Yes, it happens only once when the app is opened. So, when `getAuth()` is called before Firebase becomes online, what will be the result? Is that the cached auth data (which is "online" in my case because I closed the app before the session has expired)?

Comment: When `getAuth()` is called before Firebase goes online, you'll see the cached auth state. If the session expired between the last and current login, it is possible that you'll see a brief flicker with auth state, which is why we suggest using `getAuth()` in combination with the auth state event listener `onAuth()`.

Comment: OK, now it starts to make sense. That's pretty much what I'm experiencing. When I open the app `getAuth()` returns the cached "logged in" state, and then Firebase becomes online and `onAuth()` reports "logged out". I guess this is happening because Firebase was designed to support "offline", right?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko Correct!